# List / paired array: accessing one element

Tags: matlab

I'm using MATLAB and am calling a function that returns properties of the screen. Please see below:

```
>> Screen('resolution', 0)

ans = 

    width: 1280
   height: 1024
pixelSize: 32
       hz: 60
```

This is great, but I only want to access the 'width' parameter. I don't know whether this is classed as a 'paired array' or simply a list, but basically I'm interested in extracting just the first element; the 'width'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you get from `Screen` is an array of type `struct`. You [access the fields of a structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html#br1v5pf-1) with a `variableName.fieldName` syntax.

```
screenInfo = Screen('resolution',0);

%# access width
width = screenInfo.width
```

Answer (score 0):

`getfield(Screen('resolution', 0),'width')`